# How to get effective quantum numbers of a linear combination of $\rm H$-atom wavefunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hydrogen, orbitals

The convention for the Hydrogen atom's interpretation subject to the laws of quantum mechanics is that you can prove the quantization of $|L|$, $L_z$, and Energy through quantum numbers $\ell$, $m_\ell$, and $n$ respectively. You can check the wavefunction with some parameters as ($n$, $\ell$, $m_\ell$) based on the appropriate spherical harmonics (based on $\ell$ and $m_\ell$) and the radial solutions (based on $n$ and $\ell$). You can get $|L|$, $L_z$, and Energy as follows:

$$L_z=m_{\ell}\hbar $$
$$|L|=\sqrt{\ell(\ell+1)}\hbar  $$
$$E=\frac{-13.6 eV}{n^2} $$

If you add different wavefunctions, say with form $$A_0(A_1 \Psi_{n_1,\ell_1,m_\ell,1} + A_2 \Psi_{n_2,\ell_2,m_\ell,2} + A_3 \Psi_{n_3,\ell_3,m_\ell,3} + ...),$$ I know that this should be a solution to the equation since it is just a linear combination of different solutions to the Hydrogen atom. How would I go about solving for the "effective quantum numbers" that this linear combination has? Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

No, assuming the individual $\Psi_{nlm}$ terms are time-independent,
then a linear combination like
$$A_0(A_1 \Psi_{n_1,l_1,m_l,1} + A_2 \Psi_{n_2,l_2,m_{l,2}} + A_3 \Psi_{n_3,l_3,m_{l,3}} + ...)$$
is not a solution of the Schrödinger equation.

Since terms with different $n$ have different energies $E_n$,
you need to account for the time-dependent phase factors $e^{-iE_n t/\hbar}$.

So for example, the linear combination
$$A_0(A_1 \Psi_{n_1,l_1,m_{l,1}}\ e^{-iE_{n_1}t/\hbar}
+ A_2 \Psi_{n_2,l_2,m_{l,2}}\ e^{-iE_{n_2}t/\hbar}
+ A_3 \Psi_{n_3,l_3,m_{l,3}}\ e^{-iE_{n_3}t/\hbar}
+ ...)$$
would be a solution of the [time-dependent Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-dependent_equation)
$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\Psi=H\Psi.$$

Answer (score 0):

The quantum numbers $n,l,m$ label the different possible energy eigenstates. Moreover, $n$ labels pertains to the radial wavefunction, $l$ labels the magnitude of orbital angular momentum where $m$ labels one of its components.

In a general superposition, the state may no longer be an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, angular momentum operator (and one projection operator of it). Thus there are no $n,l,m$. One can still calculate expectation values of these operators and get an “effective” $n,l,m$ just as with any probability distribution.

Comment: I'm sorry if I come off as inexperienced (this is our current topic in class), but how would one go about calculating the expectation values of these quantum numbers? As far as I know, to get say <n> you'd calculate it with

$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \Psi^*n\Psi$ 

but I don't know if n is equivalent to some operator, or if what I've written makes sense at all. I'm again sorry for my inexperience.

Comment: @IanAngeloAragoza there’s no need to apologise when learning! And, yes. That in general is the calculate the expectation value. Now say $\psi(r)$ goes as $e^{ir/n}$ (this is the case with hydrogen) then we may differentiate it with respect to $ir$ to get $1/n$ out of it and evaluate the integral. This gives us an expectation that we can invert to get <n>. However, you know that for hydrogen the energy goes as $1/n^2$ so you can extend this definition and evaluate the energy expectation to get <n> out of that.

Comment: However, in the example superposition you’ve given, the evaluation of these expectations are more straightforward than that. Because you’ve already expressed them in an orthonormal basis. So <n> $=\sum_i {A_i}^2 n_i$  How useful these definitions are depends on the context.

Comment: Simple single differentiation is unlikely to give you good results. Don't forget about the factors such as the Laguerre polynomials for $n>1$ and $r^\ell$ for $\ell>0$. A better way would be to expand in the eigenbasis and simply get that $\langle n\rangle=|A_0|^2(|A_1|^2n_1+|A_2|^2n_2+|A_3|^2n_3+\cdots).$